# If we split data into multiple parts and process each part in parallel & combine the results, is that asynchronous or synchronous parallel algorithm?

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, parallel-processing, quicksort

If we split data into multiple parts and process each part in parallel, then combine the results of those processes/`Thread`s to form the final result, is that asynchronous or synchronous parallel algorithm?

To be specific, I have implemented QuickSort in Java

Then to make parallel QuickSort,

1. I split the array into four equal parts
2. Used Java `Thread`s to run QuickSort on each part and called `join()` on each thread to wait for their completion.
3. Finally, used merge function to merge the sorted array from each of those four `Thread`s.

Since the final result is dependent on the result of each of those threads, it seems like synchronous.
However, I have not used any locks or synchronization code, in that sense, all the threads are free from another threads.

Now, is this a *synchronous* or *asynchronous Parallel Algorithm*?

Comment: That in my opinion is synchronous parallel.  Asynchronous is something that is time-intensive, and we give some kind of output that 'we are working on it. we will notify you when it is done', and move on...  Later get a notification that your work is done..  If you divide some activity in multiple threads and make it parallel, but wait for all the threads to complete, it is synchronous parallel..

Comment: "and called join() on each thread" - this is your synchronization code.

Comment: I'm not sure it applies yet; I believe _synchronicity_ pertains to the communication of the data.  So, it would be determined in your next step, when you are utilizing the contents after the sort—if you begin using the sorted data of a list before the other lists have completed _their_ sort, it would be _asynchronous_, if you wait for the entire sort to finish, before using the data, it would be _synchronous_.

Comment: Time allowing, look into [`Java Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)s.

Answer (score 0):

For me the algorithm is asynchronous in the first part when each thread does the sort in an independent way from the others. The part in which the algorithm should wait until all threads have finished to begin the merge of the result, can be defined synchronous (join is actually a synchronization instruction).

If you need to give a definition to the whole process, I think it depends on which aspect is considered more relevant. The majority of the computation is done in the sorting part in an asynchronous way but to achieve  the result a typical synchronous mechanism is needed.